# How do you initialize and index a list of dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Currently I have something that looks like this:

```
   if width < 101:
      column_placement_0[index] = rectangles
   elif width < 201:
      column_placement_1[index] = rectangles
   elif width < 301:
       column_placement_2[index] = rectangles
```

... and so on.

Instead, I want to be able to just initialize a single columns array which stores dictionaries.

First, I feel that I would initialize an array normally...

```
columns = []
```

but then I don't know how I would reference the individual list and dictionary indices maybe something like a 2D array in Java?

```
columns[index][dict_key] = value
```

What do I do?

Comment: The way you have described it is exactly how you would do it. Did you run into a problem?

Comment: You're correct, just put the dict key in quotes if you type the name in. Column_placement[index]['key']

Comment: You only put the dictionary key in quotes if the key is a string.

Comment: Are you trying to replace `column_placement_0` and etc... with the single `column` list? It appears that 100 possible widths could go into a single `column_placement_X` ... except it has some `index` thing that has me puzzled. If two rectangles end up in the same index (is that even possible?) should one overwrite the other? If you wrote a demo script that shows what you are doing it would help. Your fragments and description leave a lot to interpretation.

Comment: If all you want to do is preallocate the list, you need to decide what you want the default value to be and then do for instance `columns = [None] * 1000`.

Comment: Okay thanks. I didn't run or compile the code that I described, I just assumed that the syntax wasn't correct. Guess I should have gone with my gut. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris
When I actually got it working it looked like your answer but with '{' rather than '[' for the brackets in which the key is passed. Thanks for your help though! Would either way have worked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So although people said my code would work as it was the final solution ended up being:

For initialization:

```
columns = [{} for i in range(10)]
```

And to store a value:

```
columns[i][key] = desired value
```

I'm kind of surprised that people just downvoted my question. The more Python I do, the more this seems like a pretty common data structure...